# "boomed the headlines" in the middle of two quoted sentences?

Tags: inversion, direct-speech

How should I parse the bold part of sentence?

> "Tall people more likely to get cancer", **boomed the headlines**, "Higher cancer risk for tall people".
>   <sub>Source: [Am I more likely to get cancer because I'm tall? - BBC News](http://www.bbc.com/news/magazine-34515952)</sub>

Shouldn't it be "which has been boomed the headlines"?

Comment: I think _boomed the headlines_ is similar to, for example, "'Blah-blah-blah,' _said Tom_" in novels. It's a case of [subject-verb inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%E2%80%93verb_inversion_in_English).

Answer (score 1):

It means the headlines is saying *"Tall people more likely to get cancer. Higher cancer risk for tall people"*.

But instead of stating it all together, it uses [subject-verb-inversion](http://www.grammaring.com/subject-verb-inversion-in-direct-speech) as applied usually in direct speech.

This is a tactic used in the sentence to grab the reader's attention.